# How to bind the IsEnabled property to an OR of two values?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, isenabled

currently when I have to make an OR of two values on the IsEnabled property of a control I end using an invisible container control (I use a Border) and setting the IsEnabled of the control and the one of the container.

Is there a better approach? If not, what is the most lightweight control for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're binding to a ViewModel, you can create an aggregate property and bind to that instead.

Comment: visit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945427/c-sharp-wpf-isenabled-using-multiple-bindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `IsEnabled` is set via binding, you may use [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) in conjunction with a [multi-value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: Honestly, I find easier my own solution :D But I get what you say.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a converter like this:

```
public class BooleanOrConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (object value in values)
        {
            if ((value is bool) && (bool)value == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("BooleanOrConverter is a OneWay converter.");
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
<myConverters:BooleanOrConverter x:Key="BooleanOrConverter" />
...
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox">
  <ComboBox.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanOrConverter}">
      <Binding ElementName="SomeCheckBox" Path="IsChecked" />
      <Binding ElementName="AnotherCheckbox" Path="IsChecked"  />
    </MultiBinding>
  </ComboBox.IsEnabled>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with a converter which or's the values passed in.